# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '@@__symbol:iterator)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, axios

I'm updating my React project from 16.13.1 to 18.2.0, in the project I'm using Axios when I updated Axios to 1.3.4 this error happened how can I fix this?

when I downgraded to the previous version it works

[image]

Comment: This is because your `react-scripts` version is not updated. Can you list your `react-scripts` version? Delete `node_modulles`, `[packager].lock` and install your deps again.

Comment: `"react-scripts": "5.0.1" ` is this ok?
`"react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"`

Comment: Okay this could be because after the `v5` upgrade polyfills are no longer supported. So if any library is using one you will have to `browserify` it or locate the `react-scripts` folder in `node_modules` then `config>webpack.config.js` modify the webpack config to allow polyfills.